Using ecl bundles in vs code for my project on CVD_DIsease Risk Prediction
how to use ecl bundles in vs code, i tried downloading ml_core and leanring_Tree ecl bundle from the dropdown box in vs code  for my project , but i kept getting import module not found error. what to do here?
kept getting errors- module not found

First, make sure you are succesfuly connected to an HPCC Systems cluster.
If so, install the HPCC Systems extension on your VSCode:

Name: ECL Language Id: hpcc-systems.ecl Description: ECL (Enterprise
Control Language) support for Visual Studio Code Version: 2.27.0
Publisher: HPCC Systems VS Marketplace Link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hpcc-systems.ecl


Then, go to the extension and you'll have all the bundles available for download, just choose which one you want and click on the cloud with a downward arrow. After a few moments the bundle will be ready for use:


